# Applying Ranks to every group in Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, rank

Say I have a simple dataset (namely df1) like this:

```
 ID     Name     Max_FileID
--------------------------------
  1      Dog          3
  1      Dog          3
  1      Dog          3
  2      Bird         1
  3      Cat          5
  3      Cat          5
```

I would like to group the dataset by ID (I have no problem with this):

```
df1.groupby('ID')
```

Then add a new column using Max_FileID + Rank.

The result should look like this

```
 ID     Name     Max_FileID     Rank
------------------------------------------
  1      Dog          3           4
  1      Dog          3           5
  1      Dog          3           6
  2      Bird         1           2
  3      Cat          5           6
  3      Cat          5           7
```

To help understand better what I am trying to achieve, here is a SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Max_FileID,
    Max_FileID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
FROM df1
```

In addition, I created a custom function:

```
def sequential_ranking(self, iterable, max_id):
  try:
    max_id = max_id - 1
    seq_nums = list()
    for num in iterable:
      max_id += 1
      seq_nums.append(max_id)
    return seq_nums
```

Not sure if there is a built-in function for it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you really want rank or just  number of occurances + Max file ID: `df['new_column'] = df['Max_FileID'].add(df.groupby('ID')['Max_FileID'].cumcount().add(1))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) function which returns the rank values in the group and if you specify the method parameter to `first` then ranks are assigned in order they appear in the group.

*You can use this:*

```
df["Rank"] = df["Max_FileID"] + df.groupby("ID")["Max_FileID"].rank(method="first").astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
>>> print(df)

   ID  Name  Max_FileID  Rank
0   1   Dog           3     4
1   1   Dog           3     5
2   1   Dog           3     6
3   2  Bird           1     2
4   3   Cat           5     6
5   3   Cat           5     7
```

Comment: Your answer is very clean. Thank you!

Comment: @september21st If this answered your question you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby then apply a custom transform by addiding a np.arange:

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('ID')['Max_FileID'].transform(lambda x: x+np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```

Comment: It is not a range from python it is a `np.array`, you can sum NumPy arrays with pandas series because pandas is built on top of NumPy

Comment: This is genius, thank you! Pardon my stupidity, is there an advantage using np.arange over range? They seem to return the same result.

Comment: Yep, NumPy is built in C so it is a lot faster than range. But if you have a small dataset it works just fine with both!

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is somewhat confusing as you said "then add a new column using Max_FileID + Rank" but the example calls the new column "Rank" even though it looks like the sum of Rank and Max_FileID.

I think you just need to use `groupby().rank()` You can drop the intermediate 'rank' column if it is not needed.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('ID').rank(method='first').astype(int)
df['newcol'] = df['Max_FileID'] + df['rank']
```

Output

```
df

=== Output: ===
   ID  Name  Max_FileID  rank  newcol
0   1   Dog           3     1       4
1   1   Dog           3     2       5
2   1   Dog           3     3       6
3   2  Bird           1     1       2
4   3   Cat           5     1       6
5   3   Cat           5     2       7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
duckdb.sql("""
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Max_FileID,
    Max_FileID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) Rank
FROM df1""")


=== Output: ===
   ID  Name  Max_FileID  rank  newcol
0   1   Dog           3     1       4
1   1   Dog           3     2       5
2   1   Dog           3     3       6
3   2  Bird           1     1       2
4   3   Cat           5     1       6
5   3   Cat           5     2       7
```